# Trouble shooting various css disappearing issue that only occurs in IE 8 & 9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, plugins, wordpress

I built my site using wordpress. I installed various plugins to add to the functionality of the site. Everything works and looks fine except when viewing the site using IE 8 & 9. All of the plugins that have a visual effect on the site lose all css when being viewed in IE. For instance the forms lose all styling when being viewed in IE, the same goes with all of the visual plugins. They all lose their styling but only in IE. I've doubled checked with the developers of the plugins and also made sure that I'm using the latest version of the plugins and they are all IE compatible but I'm still running into this issue. Im not a web designer by trade but I'm willing to learn what ever I need to, to have this issue fixed. If anyone could give me a good starting point to trouble shoot the problem it would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. I have the latest version of wordpress. The site can be found here http://www.family1st-financial.com/home

Comment: A quick look in IE and Firefox shows that the style sheet isn't even loading for some of the content.  There might be IE tags somewhere in the markup telling it not to use the stylesheets or the way the stylesheets were included using javascript are silently failing (the javascript console shows nothing in IE).

Answer (score 0):

It could be that one of the plugins is causing problems. Have you tried deactivating all plugins and reactivating them one by one, checking the styles in IE each time you enable another plugin? This may help determine if the issue is caused by a plugin conflict.